# Content porting - waiting issue

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

We faced very strange issue with content porter import. When one of the user was performing import process, that user received message:

> The process was added to the queue on the server, but wasn't started
>   yet because other processes are running.

After approx. 1 hour, the process triggered properly and import worked properly. Did not find any useful information in log file corresponding to this issue.

In which scenario this message will be displayed and what should be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To avoid overloading the CM server with heavy import/export jobs, there is a configurable cap on the number of import/export processes that can run concurrently.
The default configuration allows only one concurrent process, but this can be changed in Tridion.ContentManager.config

**EDIT (Nuno)**

Couldn't find any documentation, but this is the setting you want to change (if you want to enable multiple imports):

```
<importExport maxProcessCount="1" workingFolder="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\ImportExport\Temp" processLogLocation="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\log\ImportExport" transactionTimeout="0" userReplyTimeout="3600">
   <export threadCount="1" packagesLocation="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\ImportExport\Packages" />
   <undo undoPackagesLocation="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\ImportExport\UndoPackages" />
</importExport>
```

Comment: Does that mean if one process is already running then other user will get the message as highlighted above? Is this documented somewhere then please share the link.

Comment: Yes, it does. If you're saying the process triggered properly after an hour, that implies that another process was running for an hour.

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to increasing that setting?  What would it manifest like in the system?

Comment: As Rick states, import and export can be quite resource intensive. It will manifest itself by slowing down your server...

Comment: @NunoLinhares In the config for content porter, what does userReplyTimeout mean?

Comment: This is a separate question. :-) But the answer is: it's a limit on the amount of time (seconds) the server will wait for a user reply on a question (in interactive mode).

Comment: Using _Tridion 2013 SP1_ all the above settings were in already there, I just bounced the services, COM+ and IIS and then was able to perform a successful export :)

Comment: For SDL Web 8, simply restarting the SDL Web Content Manager Service Host windows service usually fixes this problem